# how to download and Install Latex on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: installing

how to download and Install Latex on Ubuntu 15.04?

Please Help,

Comment: Instructions on [`TeX Live - Quick install`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) or [`Full install documentation`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#installation)

Comment: If you do not need a system that you can keep up-to-date on a regular basis (for simple needs you don't) and you are new to GNU/Linux more generally , you can use the Debian/Ubuntu repositories. Something like `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` should do the trick.  But it is not that much harder to install it directly from TUG (as in Gonzalo's link), which will provide you a convenient way to update the installation whenever you wish between now and about May or 2016 (then you'll need to install TeX Live 2016).

Comment: Not just Ubuntu, but any Linux: I advise you to download the TexLive *.iso file directly from TUG. Do this via BitTorrent, as it is a very large file. Then, once downloaded, unpack the archive (no need to burn it to disc). Navigate to the folder that contains install-tl (a Perl Script). In Terminal do sudo perl install-tl. Unless you are sure that you need full capability, choose to install only the least amount of stuff. You can always add more later. Be sure that the path to binaries is in your PATH (perhaps by modifying ~/.bashrc).

Comment: thank you everyone, I finally managed to install Texlive!